# Eclipse Console problem

Tags: eclipse, console

Up until this morning Eclipse has always had the console tab open upon startup but all the sudden its nowhere to be found. Does anyone know how to add it back in? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the menu "Window/Show View/Console".

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb for missing that. Thanks!